# Sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^n(n+1/2)}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^n(n+1/2)}{n!}$. Well, sadly I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Have you tested for convergence?

Comment: Are ou familiar with the power series representation of the exponential function?

Comment: Yes, I see it now, but what about $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\pi^n}{n!}$? EDIT: Ok, that was a stupid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^n(n+1/2)}{n!} &=  \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\pi^{n} n}{n!}  + \frac1{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^{n} }{n!}  \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\pi^{n}}{(n-1)!}  + \frac1{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^{n} }{n!}  \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\pi^{n+1}}{n!}  + \frac1{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^{n} }{n!} \\
&= \pi \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\pi^{n}}{n!}  + \frac1{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^{n} }{n!} \\
 &= \pi e^\pi + \frac1{2} e^\pi 
\end{align}

In last equality I used definition of exponential function
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

Comment: this is not a satisfactory answer

Comment: I think there is typo.

Comment: Actually there is no typo. The only crime being there is no explanation. $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}n\frac{\pi^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to-1}\frac1{n!}+\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac {\pi^n}{(n-1)!}=0+\pi\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\pi^n}{n!}=\pi e^\pi$$

Comment: I hope that now is everything clear.